# Always click button when keyboard is open android-PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

How to make sure that click event always fires on button in Cordova application when my keyboard is open? When I tap on search it closes keyboard and I have to click on search again. At times it will fire click event. Check screenshot for reference-
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with cordova, but android API has `Activity#onConfigurationChanged()` callback. It's conjucted with AndroidManifest's `android:configChanges="keyboard"`

Comment: @nickalchemist Is it solved? Pls give me the solution